# Compile-time checks for JPA entities and queries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, static-analysis

Some IDEs (I'm looking at you, IntelliJ IDEA) are able to perform some static checking of both JPA entity classes, as well as queries, including parameters.

Are there any ways to do the same thing at compile time, so that such checks could be integrated into the build process, similar to running unit tests? Obviously, a good unit test suite will exercise all of the entities and queries, but it would be nice to be able to have this extra level of validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [JPA Metamodel Generator support](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html), so you can use the Metamodel classes when building your Criteria API queries. This will give you a compile-time safety guarantee for the query building process.

But this doesn't exonerate you from adding a thorough [integration testing routine](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-integration-testing-strategies/) so you can validate the whole data access layer and even the transaction management support.

Especially Criteria API, which can [generate some unexpected SQL queries](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-always-check-criteria-api-sql-queries/). That's why it's good practice to [examine and validate all generated SQL queries](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-log-jdbc-statements/).

My favorite check is to ensure the [actual SQL query count](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-detect-the-n-plus-one-query-problem-during-testing/) Hibernate generates on your behalf. This can prevent N+1 query issues and give you an insight into Hibernate internal workings.